# Confiéseme = tell me?

Tags: definiciones

I have heard the following sentence in the Narcos TV series:

> Confiéseme, ¿ está arrepentida de haberse casado conmigo o qué?

Context: Pablo Escobar has decided to send his family to Germany. He is saying goodbye to his wife and says the sentence above.

What does "confiéseme" mean here? "Tell me" ? The only meaning of "confiarse" I have found in https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=confiarse was "to be overconfident".

Comment: The infinitive in this case Is "confesar", not confiar. That is, "confess to me, are you sorry to have married me or what?"

Comment: With "confiar" it would be "confíeseme". Again, a tiny accent changes the word completely...

Comment: why don't you use RAE it is way better, and your spanish is good enough to understand the RAE

Comment: @IriaPoncelaBlanco thanks for the suggestion. I like to check WR first because it puts more usual meanings first, but I also use the monolingual RAE dictionary. In this specific case, it would have not mattered which dictionary I used because I have misunderstood the verb used in the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we conjugate "confiar," we need to put the accent on the letter "i", for example

> Confíe Ud. en mí.

So that's not the verb being used here.  This verb is **confesar** (to confess).  This one is conjugated like this:

> Confiese, doña Julieta, ¿Ud. le dio la última pieza de pastel a su nieto?  (*Confess!  Did you give the last piece of cake to your grandson?

For your sentence, there is an object pronoun, so it means "Confess [to me]" -- meaning, "Tell me the truth."